# I can't get data using id

Tags: php, laravel

I can't get data with `id` it returns this: `%7Bid%7D`.

I want to get the `id` and edit the data.

Controller:

```
       public function edit($id){

        $slider = DB::table('header_sliders')->find($id);
        return   view('posts.edit',['header'=>$slider]);

       }
```

View:

```
 <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
    <form action="{{url('admin/edit')}}"  method="POST" >
    {{csrf_field()}

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Mətn</label>
        <input type="text" name="text" class="form-control"  aria-describedby="emailHelp" value="{{$header->text}}">
        <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted"></small>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Şəkil</label>
        <input type="file" name="imgName" class="form-control"  value="{{$header->imgName}}">
    </div>

    <div class="form-check">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Dəyiş</button>
  <a href="{{url('admin/edit/{id}')}}" class="edit" data-toggle="modal"><i 
  class="material-icons" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Edit">&#xE254;</i></a>
```

Comment: wouldn't your edit/update route take a route parameter so you know how to 'id' what you want to edit/update?

Comment: yes i agree. your route should be ```admin/edit/{id}```. then you can pass like ```admin/edit/32``` and you have ```$id``` in your controller

Answer (score 1):

Create a Route like this

```
Route::get('/admin/edit/{id}','UserController@edit');
```

and pass the id with your URL like this

```
YourURL..../admin/edit/11
```

This will solve your problem